# MAPI, HrQueryAllRows: Filter messages on subject

Tags: c++, email, mapi

I'm pretty much new to MAPI and haven't wrote much C++ Code.

Basically I want to read all emails in the inbox and filter them based on their subject text. So far I'm using the source code provided at the [microsoft msdn website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239795/de) which basically reads all emails from the inbox. What I want now is to not get all emails but filter them on the subject, lets say: I want all emails in my Inbox with the subject title "test".

So far I figuered out that the following line of code retrieves all the mails:

```
 hRes = HrQueryAllRows(lpContentsTable, (LPSPropTagArray) &sptCols, &sres, NULL, 0, &pRows);
```

The parameter `&sres` is from the type `SRestriction`.

I tried to implement a filter on 'test' in the subject:

```
sres.rt = RES_CONTENT;
sres.res.resContent.ulFuzzyLevel = FL_FULLSTRING;
sres.res.resContent.ulPropTag = PR_SUBJECT;
sres.res.resContent.lpProp = &SvcProps;

SvcProps.ulPropTag = PR_SUBJECT;
SvcProps.Value.lpszA = "test";
```

`ScvProps` is from the type `SPropValue`.

If i execute the application then I get 0 lines returned. If I change the String test to an empty String then I get all emails.

I'm assuming i'm using the "filter" option wrong, any ideas?

Edit: When I change the FuzzyLevel to:

```
sres.res.resContent.ulFuzzyLevel = FL_SUBSTRING;
```

then I can look for subjects that contain a single character but as soon as I add a second character I get 0 rows as result. I'm pretty sure this is just some c++ stuff that I don't understand that causes all this problems ...

Answer (score 1):

I figured the problem out.

Replacing

```
sres.res.resContent.ulFuzzyLevel = FL_FULLSTRING;
sres.res.resContent.ulPropTag = PR_SUBJECT;
SvcProps.ulPropTag = PR_SUBJECT;
```

with

```
sres.res.resContent.ulFuzzyLevel = FL_SUBSTRING;
sres.res.resContent.ulPropTag = PR_SUBJECT_A;
SvcProps.ulPropTag = PR_SUBJECT_A;
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: You might want to use PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT instead of PR_SUBJECT. The former is indexed, the latter is not.

Comment: Could you explain to me what "indexed" means in that context?

Comment: "Indexed" as in "Database index". When using PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT in a restriction, Outlook will not actually have to loop through all messages in the folder.

Comment: Ah so this improves performance then. Thank you for your suggestion!